# Loopable Scroll Website

Tags: jquery, loops, scroll

Hopefully you can help me with a script I'm looking to create. I would like to be able to scroll to the bottom of the site and when reaching the bottom the scroll would jump to the top, creating a scrollable/loop-able website both ways. Scrolling to the top would return to the bottom.

I have a `#wrapper` div that will change height as time goes by. Currently my code attempt is weak but it kinda works sometimes... but it ads a lot of extra space in the bottom and sometimes it won't scroll at all.

```
var wrapper = $("#wrapper").height();

$(document).ready(function() {   

    $('body').height( wrapper );

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
            $(window).scrollTop(1);
        }
        else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
            $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: Just... don't. That would be a nightmare for a user. Repeating content is one thing. Seemingly random and uncontrollable scrolling would infuriate me, and I'd leave your site.

Comment: That is kinda cool. Don't scroll, though.

Comment: anyway thats the effect i want to create and any help would be great. xx